# What's the best RESTful JavaScript API?

Tags: java, javascript, rest, jquery

I have to do a simple RESTful client for a webservice written in Java.

I'm thinking to use a simple HTML/JavaScript implementation... but, i don't know what's the best API for this...

I've already tried jQuery, but I think i'm doing something wrong, because it don't work well...

Someone know a CRUD tutorial with jQuery, or other JS API?

Thanks a lot!
cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be helpful to know why jQuery doesn't work well for you. The Ajax implementation should cover everything you need to talk to a RESTful webservice. But here are two frameworks that implement an improved RESTful model wrappers:

- [Backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) Model
- [JavaScriptMVC $.Model](http://javascriptmvc.com/docs.html#&who=jQuery.Model)

There are probably more and which one is the best will depend entirely on your needs.

Comment: yea, I was doing a big mistake with the jQuery.. some time later, I discover my mistake,a nd now, it's working correct. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that the API you are calling and your client code are on different domains? If so JSONP is an option (if the API supports it).

Comment: it is in same domain, but i solve it. thanks